# Python using recursion to change certain values in list

Tags: python, recursion

This is a project for school so I do not want the answer, I only want a point in the right direction because I like figuring things out for myself. However, I am stuck with this one. Recursion makes some sense to me but I have not used it much. What I am doing is mimicking the autofill function of paint. So I will get a file like this:
....xx....
...x..x...
...x..x...
...x..x...
....xx....

I am given coordinates from which to start autofilling the matrix with X's. I know how to validate and all that jazz, what I am having trouble with is understanding how to not go out of range with my recursive function. I always receive an error saying maximum recursion occurred. Here is my attempt at the function:

```
def autoFill(x, y, rows, columns, matrix):

    if(matrix[y][x] == "."):
        matrix[y][x] = "x"
    if(y-1 >= 0):
        autoFill(x, y-1, rows, columns, matrix)
    elif(y+1 <= rows):
        autoFill(x, y+1, rows, columns, matrix)
    elif(x-1 >= 0):
        autoFill(x-1, y, rows, columns, matrix)
    elif(x+1 <= columns):
        autoFill(x+1, y, rows, columns, matrix)

    return matrix
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It looks like you forgot to include the `def` line in the program: could you put it in?

Comment: It might help you to watch it go one step at a time, by having it print out the matrix and the `x` and `y` arguments at each step. You should see it pegging against a wall, or bouncing back and forth, or something else it shouldn't be doing. That will be your best clue as to what it's doing wrong.

Comment: Oops forgot about that, thanks

Comment: @user3006282: The edited version is now an `IndentationError`.

Comment: @abarnert thanks, tried it again, not used to putting code into this

Comment: @user3006282: No big deal; anyone who's trying to get used to it rather than force everyone else to deal with unreadable code is a good user, even if he hasn't gotten used to it yet. (And even once you _do_ get used to it, sometimes things can be a little screwy. That's what the preview area at the bottom is for…)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first problem is the bottom and right edges:

```
elif(y+1 <= rows):
    autoFill(x, y+1, rows, columns, matrix)
```

The range is all the numbers from 0 to `rows`, *not* including `rows`. So, when `y+1 == rows`, `y=1` is out of range. So you need to change that `<=` to `<`.

---

Your second problem is that you don't have a base case. One of those four conditions will *always* be true (unless `rows == columns == 0`), so you will always recurse, which means you're guaranteed to recurse infinitely.

You need some condition in which you *don't* recurse. For example:

```
if <some condition in which you don't need to go any further>:
    return
# now do the rest of your code
```

What *is* that condition? Well, that's the part you have to figure out. You could keep track of the direction(s) you're filling and not recurse if you hit the edges in that direction, or keep track of whether you've already filled from a given point (hint: that one's much easier than it sounds), or…

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! This actually makes a lot more sense now, I should be able to figure it out now. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You should only recurse if you filled in the current position. If the current position was already an "x", stop recursing.

P.S. this is how I prefer to code this particular pattern, with bounds checking done in one place instead of for each recursive call.

```
def autoFill(x, y, rows, columns, matrix):
    if x < 0 or y < 0 or x >= columns or y >= rows:
        return
    if matrix[y][x] != '.':
        return
    matrix[y][x] = 'x'
    autoFill(x - 1, y, rows, columns, matrix)
    autoFill(x + 1, y, rows, columns, matrix)
    autoFill(x, y - 1, rows, columns, matrix)
    autoFill(x, y + 1, rows, columns, matrix)
```

Comment: My one last question is do you think my school would count this as cheating? I didn't really think about it, I mean all my code is 100% original, I just seriously needed help on this one part which is the main part of the project.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your program will recurse back and forth indefinitely - furthermore, the program does not consider the boundaries at all - even if the program finished it would be equivalent to filling completely with x's, rather than a boundary around the Xs already created (though if this is what you want to do, I'm sorry for misintepreting).

This is a common computing problem known as a 'flood-fill problem'. After your assignment you might want to consider looking up some cool ways of doing this, both faster and with more efficient memory usage.